# Dynamically loading Quilljs

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to dynamically load Quilljs, however Firefox throws the error : *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: module.Quill is not a constructor*

Although In QuillJs source code Quill (the default export) is a class with a constructor. What am I missing?

Here is my code so far:

```
import("quill").then(module => {
      let quill = new module.Quill('#quill-container', {
        modules: {...},
        .
        .
        .
      });      
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Quill, but if it is exported through the `default` export (and there is a bundler in place that resolves `import("quill")` instead of having a relative or absolute URL), it should be possible to use it like this:

```
import("quill").then(module => {
  const Quill = module.default; // get the default export and name it to "Quill"
  let instance = new Quill(...);
  ...
});
```

Comment: Somehow that works while my original code is not. Any particular reason the line ```const Quill = module.default;``` is required?
The last line in Quill source Code reads ```export default Quill;``` from which I assumed the exports module.Quill exists ( and for that matter console.log(mdoule.Quill) does print out an object

Comment: A module has one `default` export and can have multiple named exports. In static imports it looks like this: `import TheDefaultImport, {SomethingNamed} from "./module.js"`. It's clear there what the `default` export is and what is named. In the dynamic import with the promise, it's not as clear and therefore its just the name. You should be able to do `let instance = new module.default(...);` as well

Comment: I guess this is done because of the possibilities of name clashes when the default export is an object with properties that have the same name as a named export